# google analytic shows data for the page I don't have on my website

Tags: php, google-analytics, web-traffic

My homepage is www.exaqmple.com and developed in php but in my analytics direct traffic landing page is showing data for another one like www.example.com/http://www.example.com/index.aspx and it shows average session time also but whenever i try to open that page 404 error is coming. Why this happening and how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a victim of GA spam.
This is because the UA code is visible in the html, and anyone can find it and use it to create referral traffic.
The idea is that you as the admin is looking at the statistics and wonder what that referral page is and clicks on it.
It may be harmless or can be flooded with spam popups or even viruses.

To make sure you don't get this you need to verify that the statistics that is shown on GA is coming from *real users* on **your page**.
You can do that by adding a dimension to your GA send code that you in GA admin use to filter on.

Example:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  'Y'
 });
```

Here I add dimension1 to the send code with the value Y.
This means if a user is on your page and use your GA JavaScript code it will always send dimension1 as value 'Y'.
If you add this and let it stay on for a day or two, just to make GA collect some data of it.

Then go in GA admin section and choose filter.
Now you want to **exclude** all traffic that does not have dimension1 as value 'Y'.

This means any spam traffic is not picked up in your report.
Only if someone actually looks at your GA code will they be able to put spam in your statistics, but usually the spam is generated by software that is (yet) not smart enough to do that.